# Boto3 throws ConnectionReset and Protocol Errors when reading files from S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, boto3, connection-reset

I am performing analysis in a Jupyter Notebook on my local computer and reading data from S3 to do so. When I close a notebook and open another to read another file in, I get the following error:

`ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))`

Since the problem seems to be with an existing connection, and according to [this thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060070/ConnectionResetError-WinError-An-existing-connecti) I tried to wait and close my existing connections. Boto3 does not appear to have a `.close()` or equivalent for its `s3client.get_object()` (see code below)

My first connection on startup does not produce this error.

When I shut down my computer and start it up again I can avoid this error after having already seen it.

When I restart my computer, the error persists.

How can I close the connection without needing to restart my computer?

```py
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import boto3.session
from botocore.client import Config

config = Config(connect_timeout=500, retries={'max_attempts': 5}, read_timeout=1000)


cred = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
ACCESS_KEY = cred.access_key
SECRET_KEY = cred.secret_key
SESSION_TOKEN = cred.token

s3client = boto3.client('s3', 
                        aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY, 
                        aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY, 
                        aws_session_token = SESSION_TOKEN,
                        config = config
                       )

response = s3client.get_object(Bucket='mydatabucket', Key='mydata.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'])
```

Here is the traceback and error I get instead of the expected pandas dataframe stored as `df`:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in _error_catcher(self)
    359             try:
--> 360                 yield
    361 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in read(self, amt, decode_content, cache_content)
    441                 cache_content = False
--> 442                 data = self._fp.read(amt)
    443                 if amt != 0 and not data:  # Platform-specific: Buggy versions of Python.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in read(self, amt)
    446             b = bytearray(amt)
--> 447             n = self.readinto(b)
    448             return memoryview(b)[:n].tobytes()


C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in readinto(self, b)
    490         # (for example, reading in 1k chunks)
--> 491         n = self.fp.readinto(b)
    492         if not n and b:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    588             try:
--> 589                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    590             except timeout:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)
   1051                   self.__class__)
-> 1052             return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   1053         else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    910             if buffer is not None:
--> 911                 return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    912             else:

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4d25be33c7b8> in <module>
      1 response = s3client.get_object(Bucket='mydatabucket', Key='mydata.csv')
----> 2 audit = pd.read_csv(response['Body'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    433 
    434     try:
--> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
    436     finally:
    437         parser.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1137     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1138         nrows = _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
-> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1140 
   1141         # May alter columns / col_dict

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1993     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1994         try:
-> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1996         except StopIteration:
   1997             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\response.py in read(self, amt)
     76         """
     77         try:
---> 78             chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
     79         except URLLib3ReadTimeoutError as e:
     80             # TODO: the url will be None as urllib3 isn't setting it yet

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in read(self, amt, decode_content, cache_content)
    457                         # raised during streaming, so all calls with incorrect
    458                         # Content-Length are caught.
--> 459                         raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
    460 
    461         if data:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    128                 value = type()
    129             try:
--> 130                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    131             except StopIteration as exc:
    132                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in _error_catcher(self)
    376             except (HTTPException, SocketError) as e:
    377                 # This includes IncompleteRead.
--> 378                 raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
    379 
    380             # If no exception is thrown, we should avoid cleaning up

ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to close or delete the client to re-open it later. Each call to AWS is a distinct API request to an endpoint for that service with no long-term connection maintained.

So you can access multiple files in one connection, and you don't have to worry about closing and re-opening connections to S3.

Comment: If that isn't the cause to my error, what is? And how do I get my files?